# Numbers: ordinals and cardinals

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, politeness, numbers, style

I would be grateful if anyone could help. I'm confused about using ordinal and cardinal numbers in such examples:

If I want to get a larger size of shoes, what should I ask for?

> Can I have forty-second size (42)?

or

> Can I have forty-two size?

If both sound strange or artificial to you, how would you ask?

Next example:

If I'm seeking for room #10, my question should be

> Where is the tenth room?

or

> Where is the ten room?

or

> Where is the room number ten?
>
> (sounds most appropriate to me, still wondering if the first or second are Okay)

Thanks a lot in advance. If there is anything I can read, please feel free to share.

Comment: I think neither cardinal nor ordinal are accurate terms here.

Comment: What would you use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English puts the cardinal after the word ['size'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/size), like *a size seven hat*.

So for the first example, the correct expression is *size forty-two*:

> Can I have size forty-two?

---

For your other example, both of these expressions are idiomatic:

> Where is room ten?
>
> Where is room number ten?

It is possible to refer to a room with an ordinal, but it will indicate its *location*, not its *number*.

> Jacob's office is the tenth room on the right.

Comment: Note that size 42 is (most likely) a Continental European shoe size - English-speaking countries use other shoe size systems.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question would be to say "Can I have a size forty-two (shoe)?". Forty-second is used as an indicator of a counting distance from some arbitrary other set of shoes, while forty-two is used to specify a specific shoe size.

Your second question has the same answer, for the same reasons. Asking for room #10 specifies a room that has that number on the door. Asking for the tenth room indicates you are counting 10 rooms from another room, in this case probably room #1. Both of them could have the same meaning, but if the rooms were numbered in a non-sequential way (rooms 1,3,6,8,10,4,7,2,9,5), then the 10th room from room #1 (in this example) would be room #5.